# Can't display rows in child component DataGrids MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Im using NextJS and i have a parent component called ScanningTasksUI which contains a [MUI DataGrid](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/) that then contains rows which the last cell has a button that opens 1 child component call OppGridRanges.

Right now, my problem is that when there is more than 1 row in the parent component, the rows in the child components wont show...

ScanningTasksUI:

```
"use client";
import { Box, Button, Modal, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid, GridColDef, GridColumnHeaderParams } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useEffect, useState, memo } from "react";
import { getSession } from "../supabase-server";
import { GetScanningTasksDetails } from "../api/database/get-scanning-tasks";
import { GetUserSubstrategies } from "../api/database/get-user-strategies";
import OppGridRanges from "../../components/dynamic/OppGridRanges/OppGridRanges";
import Discord from "../../components/ui/Discord/Discord";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const style = {
  position: "absolute" as "absolute",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
  width: "90%",
  height: "90%",
  bgcolor: "background.paper",
  border: "2px solid #000",
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};
const ScanningTasksUI = ({ user }) => {
  const [substrategyRows, setSubstrategyRows] = useState([]);
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const handleViewResults = async (strategyId) => {
    const substrategies = await GetUserSubstrategies(strategyId);
    setSubstrategyRows(substrategies);
  };

  const columns: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "strategy_name",
      headerName: "Strategy name",
      flex: 0.8,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Strategy name"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "sustrategy_count",
      headerName: "Substrategy Count",
      headerAlign: "left",
      flex: 0.5,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Substrategy Count"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "status",
      headerName: "Status",
      headerAlign: "left",
      type: "string",
      flex: 0.5,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Status"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "scheduled_for",
      headerName: "Schedulded Time",
      headerAlign: "left",
      type: "string",
      flex: 0.8,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Schedulded Time"}</strong>
      ),
    },

    {
      field: "finished_at",
      headerName: "Finished at",
      headerAlign: "left",
      type: "string",
      flex: 0.8,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Finished at"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "results",
      headerName: "Results",
      headerAlign: "left",
      type: "string",
      flex: 0.8,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Results"}</strong>
      ),
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <div>
          <div key={uuidv4()}>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                handleViewResults(params.row.strategy_id);
                setShowModal(true);
              }}
            >
              View Results
            </Button>
            <Modal
              open={showModal}
              style={{ overflow: "scroll" }}
              key={uuidv4()}
            >
              <Box sx={style} style={{ overflow: "scroll" }} key={uuidv4()}>
                <div>
                  <Button
                    style={{ float: "right" }}
                    onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}
                  >
                    Return to tasks
                  </Button>
                  {substrategyRows.map((value, i) => (
                    <div
                      key={uuidv4()}
                      style={{
                        zIndex: 10,
                      }}
                    >
                      <OppGridRanges
                        key={uuidv4()}
                        index={(i + 1).toString()}
                        task_id={params.row.id} // Pass the correct task_id
                        substrategy_id={value.substrategy_id}
                      />
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </Box>
            </Modal>
          </div>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];
  const [showResults, setShowResults] = useState(false);
  const [taskRows, setTaskRows] = useState([]);

  var tempTasks = [];
  const setStr = async () => {
    setTaskRows([]);
    tempTasks = await GetScanningTasksDetails(user.id);
    tempTasks.forEach((x) => {
      setTaskRows((prevRows) => [
        ...prevRows,
        {
          id: x.task_id,
          strategy_id: x.strategy_id,
          strategy_name: x.name,
          sustrategy_count: x.substrategy_count,
          scheduled_for: x.scheduled_for,
          status: x.status,
          finished_at: x.finished_at,
        },
      ]);
    });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const callFunctionOne = async () => {
      if (user != null) {
        await setStr();
      }
    };
    callFunctionOne();
  }, [user]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="max-w-6xl mx-auto pt-8 sm:pt-24 pb-8 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div className="sm:flex sm:flex-col sm:align-center">
          <h1 className="text-4xl font-extrabold text-white sm:text-center sm:text-6xl">
            Scanning Tasks Report
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="w-3/4 m-auto">
        <Box
          sx={{
            height: 400,
            width: "100%",
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "white",
          }}
        >
          <DataGrid
            rows={taskRows}
            columns={columns}
            key={uuidv4()}
            pageSizeOptions={[5]}
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            initialState={{
              sorting: {
                sortModel: [{ field: "finished_at", sort: "desc" }],
              },
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: {
                  pageSize: 5,
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        </Box>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Discord />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default memo(ScanningTasksUI);
```

And here is OppGridRanges:

```
"use client";
import { Button, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import {
  DataGrid,
  GridColDef,
  GridColumnHeaderParams,
  GridToolbarFilterButton,
} from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useCallback, useEffect, useState, memo, useMemo } from "react";
import { GetOppTimestampRanges } from "../../../app/api/database/get-task-results";
import { GetUserSubstrategyParameters } from "../../../app/api/database/get-user-strategies";
import CandlestickGraph from "../CandlestickGraph/CandlestickGraph";
interface props {
  index: String;
  task_id: String;
  substrategy_id: String;
}

const OppGridRanges = ({ index, task_id, substrategy_id }: props) => {
  var fetchedRows;
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);
  const [selectedTicker, setSelectedTicker] = useState("");
  const [tickerList, setTickerList] = useState([]);
  const [parameters, setParameters] = useState("");
  const [refDataGrid, setRefDataGrid] = useState(null);

  const columnsSingleMulti: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "ticker",
      headerName: "Ticker",
      flex: 0.2,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Ticker"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timeframe",
      headerName: "Timeframe",
      flex: 0.2,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Timeframe"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timestamp_1",
      headerName: "Start of range",
      flex: 0.8,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Start of range"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timestamp_2",
      headerName: "End of range",
      headerAlign: "left",
      flex: 0.8,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"End of range"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timestamp_length",
      headerName: "Length of range",
      headerAlign: "left",
      flex: 0.3,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Length of range"}</strong>
      ),
    },
  ];
  const columnsIndicatorRSI: GridColDef[] = [
    {
      field: "ticker",
      headerName: "Ticker",
      flex: 0.2,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Ticker"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timeframe",
      headerName: "Timeframe",
      flex: 0.2,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Timeframe"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timestamp_1",
      headerName: "Start of range",
      flex: 0.8,
      headerAlign: "left",
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"Start of range"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "timestamp_2",
      headerName: "End of range",
      headerAlign: "left",
      flex: 0.8,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"End of range"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "rsi_low",
      headerName: "RSI Low",
      headerAlign: "left",
      flex: 0.3,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"RSI Low"}</strong>
      ),
    },
    {
      field: "rsi_high",
      headerName: "RSI High",
      headerAlign: "left",
      flex: 0.3,
      renderHeader: (params: GridColumnHeaderParams) => (
        <strong>{"RSI High"}</strong>
      ),
    },
  ];
  async function fetchRows() {
    setRefDataGrid("indicator_rsi");
    fetchedRows = await GetOppTimestampRanges(task_id, substrategy_id);
    //each ticker
    fetchedRows.map((x) => {
      x.result.map((value, i) => {
        setRows((prevRows) => [
          ...prevRows,
          {
            id: uuidv4(),
            ticker: x.ticker,
            timeframe: x.timeframe,
            timestamp_1: value.timestamp_1,
            timestamp_2: value.timestamp_2,
            rsi_low: value.rsi_low,
            rsi_high: value.rsi_high,
            timestamp_length: 3,
          },
        ]);
        if (value.rsi_low != null) {
          setRefDataGrid("indicator_rsi");
        } else if (value.ma_type1 != null) {
          setRefDataGrid("indicator_crossover");
        } else {
          setRefDataGrid("multisingle");
        }
      });
    });
    var tickers = [];
    fetchedRows.forEach((x) => tickers.push(x["ticker"]));
    setTickerList(
      tickers.filter((value, index, array) => array.indexOf(value) === index)
    );

    var params = await GetUserSubstrategyParameters(substrategy_id);
    setParameters(params);
  }

  function getPeriod1WithOffset() {
    fetchedRows.forEach((x) => {
      if (x[0].ticker.toLowerCase() == selectedTicker.toLowerCase()) {
        var d = new Date(x[0].timestamp_1);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1);
        return d;
      }
    });
    return new Date();
  }
  function getPeriod2WithOffset() {
    fetchedRows.forEach((x) => {
      if (x[0].ticker.toLowerCase() == selectedTicker.toLowerCase()) {
        var d = new Date(x[x.length - 1].timestamp_2);
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
        return d;
      }
    });
    return new Date();
  }
  function getTimeframe() {
    fetchedRows.forEach((x) => {
      if (x[0].ticker.toLowerCase() == selectedTicker.toLowerCase()) {
        return x[0].timeframe;
      }
    });
    return "15m";
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const callFunctionOne = async () => {
      await fetchRows();
    };
    callFunctionOne();
    // console.log("task_id: " + task_id);
    // console.log("substrategy_id: " + substrategy_id);
  }, [refDataGrid]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Typography style={{ color: "black" }} variant="h5" className="py-5">
          Substrategy #{index} {parameters}
        </Typography>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Typography style={{ color: "black" }} variant="h6" className="pb-5">
          Table View
        </Typography>
        {refDataGrid === "multisingle" && (
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            getRowId={(row) => row.id}
            key={uuidv4()}
            columns={columnsSingleMulti}
            pageSizeOptions={[5]}
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            autoHeight
            initialState={{
              sorting: {
                sortModel: [{ field: "timestamp_2", sort: "desc" }],
              },
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: {
                  pageSize: 5,
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        {refDataGrid === "indicator_rsi" && (
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            getRowId={(row) => row.id}
            key={uuidv4()}
            columns={columnsIndicatorRSI}
            pageSizeOptions={[5]}
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            autoHeight
            initialState={{
              sorting: {
                sortModel: [{ field: "timestamp_2", sort: "desc" }],
              },
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: {
                  pageSize: 5,
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        )}
        {/* {refDataGrid === "indicator_crossover" && (
          <DataGrid
            rows={rows}
            getRowId={(row) => row.id}
            key={uuidv4()}
            columns={columns}
            pageSizeOptions={[5]}
            disableRowSelectionOnClick
            autoHeight
            initialState={{
              sorting: {
                sortModel: [{ field: "timestamp_2", sort: "desc" }],
              },
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: {
                  pageSize: 5,
                },
              },
            }}
          />
        )} */}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Typography style={{ color: "black" }} variant="h6" className="py-5">
          Graph View (Coming soon!)
        </Typography>
        {/* <div className="grid grid-flow-row gap-4">
          {tickerList.map((ticker) => (
            <div key={ticker}>
              <Button onClick={() => setSelectedTicker(ticker)}>
                {ticker}
              </Button>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div> */}

        {/* <CandlestickGraph
          ticker={selectedTicker}
          period1={getPeriod1WithOffset()}
          period2={getPeriod2WithOffset()}
          timeframe={getTimeframe()}
          chartOpps={[]}
        /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default memo(OppGridRanges);
```